# Does c# have something like 'child' namespaces, or package scoping like in Java?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I don't understand why an explicit reference isn't required in this situation:

```
//SomeStaticClass.cs
namespace WhyDontINeedUsingStatement {

    public static class SomeStaticClass {
        public static string Thingy {
            get { return "Behold! A thingy!"; }
        }
    }

    public class SomeNonStaticClass {
        public void DoSomethingUseful() {
            var foo = 9; 
        }
    }
}

// /SomeNamespace/SomeBoringClass.cs
namespace WhyDontINeedUsingStatement.SomeNamespace {
    public class SomeBoringClass {
        public static void DoSomething() {
            var whatever = SomeStaticClass.Thingy;

            var blah = new SomeNonStaticClass();
            blah.DoSomethingUseful();            
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this require a `using WhyDontINeedUsingStatement` at the top?  Aren't these separate namespaces, even though they start with the same thing?

I get that C# namespaces aren't quite the same thing as Java packages (and don't affect access control), but not why the second class is able to reference stuff from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to C# Language Specification Version 5.0, Section 9.2, it seems like using the `.` in a namespace declaration is syntactic sugar :

> The qualified-identifier of a namespace-declaration may be a single
>   identifier or a sequence of identifiers separated by “.” tokens. The
>   latter form permits a program to define a nested namespace without
>   lexically nesting several namespace declarations. For example,

```
namespace N1.N2
{
    class A {}
    class B {}
}
```

> is semantically equivalent to

```
namespace N1
{
    namespace N2
    {
        class A {}
        class B {}
    }
}
```

So from inside of `N2` you can see `N1`, hence why you can use it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did find information on nested namespaces, but did not make the connection that this allowed you to access members of parents within the children.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have VS installed, you probably have the specs on your computer as well. They don't read as interesting as Game of Thrones, but they do have some valuable info it seems :)